# How do I list out ports in a specific format?

Tags: firewall, port

I would like to print ports, their status, and what program is running on them in a format like this:

```
port#:portStatus:program
```

in order to make a script that can ask me if I would like to make a firewall rule for the port. It could be a different format that is easy to get the desired information from, but I would prefer the example I gave. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, have you tried something so far?

Comment: No, I have been racking my brain as to how I could easily separate the info from a basic netstat -tulpn, but haven’t had any luck.

Comment: `ss` is generally a better choice than `netstat` if that is available.

Comment: @icarus definitely, anything that works!

Comment: Try `sudo lsof -i` or `sudo lsof -i tcp:22`. Read `man lsof`.